# How to get my android device to check for system updates on start up?

Tags: android, updates, minix, automatic-updates

I'm looking for any way to check for 'System Updates' automatically when I turn on my android device.

I am working on a project in school and we are using a MINIX box which is running Android OS, but that is beside the point, and what I am asking is that, is there a way to automatically get the device to check for 'System Updates' when it turns on without the user having to press anything? 
So in other words, is there a way that I can get the Android box to automatically click the button 'System Updates' as shown in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49vLh.png

Thankyou for considering to help me! I am a 15 year old kid, in need of help :)